# git: how can you ever the `R`, `C` and `U` flags in git-status

Tags: git, status, flags

Reading the [git-status man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git-status), I read about the flags:

```
`R`: file renamed
`C`: file copied
`U`: file updated
```

But how would you ever get these flags in the git-status command. `git mv`, results in an `A` flag, there is no `git cp`. Are these flags deprecated?

Comment: They are not deprecated.  What flags are you passing for rename detection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R` and `U` are quite simple:

```
$ git init
$ touch ag
$ git add a
$ git commit -mm
$ git mv a b
$ git status --short
R  a -> b
```

```
$ git init
$ touch a
$ git add a
$ git commit -mm
$ git checkout -b dev
$ echo a > a
$ git commit -amm
$ git checkout -
$ echo b > a
$ git commit -amm
$ git rebase dev
$ git status --short
UU a
```

But I don't know how to simulate `C`.  In this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22798751/3691891 it says that it might be
not possible today although it's still described in
`Documentation/git-status.txt` in git source code.

Comment: If `git status` set various extra internal flags, or grew options to set them, *then* you could get `C` statuses. Unless and until that ever happens, you can't.